# Sci-fi movie about a woman in an asylum / psychiatric ward

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this movie when I was a kid around the early-to-mid '80-s - I only remember a few details of it but what I do remember left quite an impression so I'd like to find it and watch it again.

Here are the things I recall:

- I think the movie was made in the late '60-s or '70-s (visually it was somewhat similar to Silent Running or Logan's Run - big white spaces). The visuals (especially for its time) would've definitely classified this as a sci-fi.
- (Added for @NathanGriffith's comment) The visual setting was somewhat futuristic: the story is set on Earth in a near-ish future US.
- I *think* this was an American stand-alone movie (it wasn't a series). (It is possible that it wasn't American - we had European movies, too, so it could be French / German / etc. but somehow I think it was American.)
- I saw it in Hungary, on TV around 1983(-ish).
- I think it was a full-length movie (60+ minutes long) but I cannot be certain.
- The protagonist is a young or middle-aged woman who is locked up in an asylum or psychiatric ward but she had been put there as part of some conspiracy.
- The asylum is a nice place with a large park around it where the patients are supposedly kept happy and safe but the director of the place (a doctor) works with someone who wants to make this woman disappear.
- She's being told by the doctor that she needs treatment for some imaginary condition. She's basically being kept as a prisoner as a favor to someone.
- The one thing I remember very clearly about this movie is that the woman tries to escape once but the park is fenced around by a laser fence. The fence posts are tall white columns (separated by maybe 4 meters) that are connected by 5 or 6 horizontal pulsating white-red laser beams - if something tries to cross these, they get burned. She somehow figures out a way to cross over to the road on the other side of the fence and tries to hitch a ride. The cars are mostly white. The guards realize that she's gone and they search for her. Eventually a car stops to pick her up and it turns out the driver works for the doctor so she's taken back to the institute.
- In one scene as she's trying to cross the laser fence, she's burning some object that touches the laser beams but I don't remember if it's a tree branch or herself or something else. She definitely knows that the laser beams burn whatever they touch.
- At one point in the movie (earlier) there's a short scene that shows a (white?) guard house where the guard can turn the laser fence on or off. At some point someone comes to visit her (or maybe to visit the doctor) and their car has to stop by the guard house to enter the park.
- Eventually a friend of hers (her love interest or maybe a private detective?) starts looking for her and finds her so she's freed at the end. The doctor is arrested.(?)

Comment: Hi, what about this movie made you think it was science fiction? From the description so far there don't seem to be any sci-fi elements.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Laser fences?

Comment: @Buzz laser fences aren't science fiction though - they really exist e.g. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-35341775

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Calling the things in that article "laser fences" is just (misleading) branding.  They are not fences (which block passage) but motion detectors.  The question describes actual fences made of lasers, which do not exist.

Comment: @Buzz I'm not going to debate the fine points of what constitutes a laser fence, my question is for the OP - perhaps there are more sci fi elements to the story that are not mentioned above that might help identify it.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths The entire visual setting was somewhat futuristic. The story was set on Earth in a near-ish future US, if I remember right. I was some sort of detective mystery wrapped in sci-fi elements but no spaceships, deep space and the like. For the time when it was made, it would've definitely been classified as sci-fi. I'll add these details to the question.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I updated the question with a bit more detail that I think I recall.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_set_in_psychiatric_hospitals might help...long list though.

Comment: @Brandon_J I looked through (some of) that list and couldn't identify the movie. Most of those are classified as horror movies - I wouldn't call mine a horror (my parents let me watch it).

Comment: Do you remember any names at all - town, hospital name, doctor name, protagonist name? TV channel it would have been on? Do you remember whose orders the doctor was following? Just trying to jog your memory in a google-able form.

Comment: @Brandon_J I'm sorry, no. I was a kid when I saw this film and I don't remember much more. I think the doctor was following maybe some government orders but I'm very unsure - this may even be totally off. The laser fence is the one thing I remember fairly clearly.

Comment: I remember a 1970s movie in which a lot of young men and women lived in a pleasant building set in parkland which they were not allowed to leave. There were nice-seeming doctors keeping them healthy, but also guards who weren't so nice. Occasionally one of the young people would be taken away and the others would be told that that lucky person had gone to "America". It turned out that all the young people were clones of evil rich people. The clones had been created and were being kept alive and healthy so that eventually the mind of the rich person could be transplanted into a younger body. >

Comment: > This would, of course, kill the clone. I think I remember one or more of the clones - either a young woman alone or a woman and a man - trying to escape into "America", having begun to suspect that something sinister was afoot, but I  must have only seen the first half of the movie because I have no idea what happened next.  What leads me to think this is the movie xxbbcc is looking for is that the visual appearance was like the TV series Logan's Run, very clean and white. Also the make-up and hairstyles were very 1970s. Unfortunately I can't remember the title. I saw it on TV in the UK.

Comment: @xxbbcc, some more searching has revealed that the film I remember seeing on TV in the UK was *[Parts: The Clonus Horror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts:_The_Clonus_Horror)* made in 1979. I am not sure whether it was the film you are seeking. The Wikipedia plot summary  mentions a male clone escaping, not a female as you remembered. The ending is sadder than you describe. OTOH the facility being an apparently pleasant place aligns with what you said. The clones are shown as being childlike and naive due to their ignorance, which might explain why you remembered it as a psychiatric ward.

Comment: @Lostinfrance hmm, I can't tell. You're right, the story / time frame are really close but visually it doesn't match the few images that I remember. (I found Clonus on Youtube.) I think the one Im looking for had more sets built - this one looked like a college campus.